# XML Viewer Not Working for All Users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xml-viewer-web-part

I added an XML Viewer web part on my page to display a twitter RSS feed. When I view the page I can see the feed perfectly. However, no other users can view this web part on my page. I'm confused because this web part doesn't exist on a personal view and the permissions to the site are wide-open.

Any suggestions as to why this web part would only display for me and not everyone?

Comment: Audience Targeting?

Comment: @tylerrrr07 - This is SharePoint Foundation. No Audience Targeting in this version of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unknown reason, the page that I added the XML Viewer web part to was checked out in SharePoint designer. Checking in this page in SharePoint designer made the web part visible to all users.